# Incorrect Syntax Near ')' inside stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am currently receiving the following error when trying to run my dynamic sql below; is there something I'm missing that's causing this error to be thrown?....

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure calc, Line 32 Incorrect syntax
>   near ')'.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE calc(@pC INT, @Array1 varchar(500) ,@pT VARCHAR(15), @pTN VARCHAR(15), @pPK BIGINT, @pCI FLOAT, @pFK BIGINT)
        AS 
        BEGIN
        --calculate peer statistics for level of peer group   
        DECLARE @sMI FLOAT, @num25 FLOAT, @num75 FLOAT, @num25V FLOAT, @num75V FLOAT
        DECLARE @sMD FLOAT, @sME FLOAT, @sIQ FLOAT, @sSD FLOAT, @sMin FLOAT, @sMax FLOAT, @sDiff FLOAT
        DECLARE @sLK BIGINT, @sNL BIGINT, @sNI BIGINT
        DECLARE @sUNC NVARCHAR(5)
        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @SQL =  'IF ('+@pFK+' = 0) 
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO '+@pTN+' (fldBA) VALUES (2); 
                END
            ELSE  
                BEGIN  
                    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+@pTN+' WHERE fldFPK = '+@pFK+' and fldPK='+@pPK+' and fldCIA='+@pCI+') > 0)
                        BEGIN           
                            UPDATE '+@pTN+' SET fldAVA = 0, fldPK = '+@pPK+', fldDTA = GETDATE(), fldCIA = '+@pCI+',
                            fldME = '+@sME+',fldMD = '+@sMD+',fldIQ = '+@sIQ+',fldSD = '+@sSD+', fldND = '+@pC+' + 1,
                            fldNI = '+@sNI+', fldNL = '+@sNL+', fldMin = '+@sMin+', fldMax = '+@sMax+',fldUNC = '+@sUNC+'
                            WHERE fldFPK = '+@pFK+' and fldPK = '+@pPK+' and fldCIAc = '+@pCI+'
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN               
                            INSERT INTO '+@pTN+' (fldFPK, fldAVA, fldPK, fldDTA, fldCIA,fldMean,fldMD,fldIQ,fldSD,fldND,fldNI,fldNL,fldMin,fldMax,fldUNC) VALUES('+@pFK+', 0, '+@pPK+', GETDATE(), 
                            '+@pCI+', '+@sME+', '+@sMD+','+@sIQ+','+@sSD+','+@pC+'+ 1, '+@sNI+', '+@sNL+', '+@sMin+', '+@sMax+', '+@sUNC+')
                        END
                END'

exec @SQL
```

Comment: Initial quick glance, can you show an example call to this sproc that gives that problem, complete with the actual parameter values?

Comment: Use `select @SQL` or `print @SQL` and check the sql string.

Comment: @Kaf I'm not sure how to use print in this context, any hints?

Comment: On `SSMS`, Comment out the stored procedure creating part leaving the parameters and assign your values to them. At the end `print @SQL`

Comment: I get the following error 'Error converting data type varchar to bigint.' on the first line of the dynamic statement, what would be causing this? Even when I substitute the variable @pFK with a 0 I still get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied and pasted the procedure in SQL Server Management Studio. You don't have any syntax error.
You have just to close the statement `CREATE PROCEDURE` with an `END`, because you started it with a `BEGIN`. You can do that in this way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calc(@pC INT, @Array1 varchar(500) ,@pT VARCHAR(15), @pTN VARCHAR(15), @pPK BIGINT, @pCI FLOAT, @pFK BIGINT)
    AS 
    BEGIN

    /* BODY OF PROCEDURE */

    SET @SQL = ''

    EXEC @SQL

    END
```

Comment: Haha, yeah, my issue was separate, or at least I thought it was. All I needed was the 'end!' XD